# Multiple instances of same fragment type with different ViewModel type based on argument passed to fragment

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger-2, android-viewmodel, android-viewpager2

I have application with ViewPager2. All pages in it are instances of same type fragmet. All pages are displaying some lists in a recyclerview, of different data types. Data are populated from some API endpoint, using Retrofit calls.

I'm using dagger 2 to inject viewmodels.

Everything is working fine with one page. Now I want to create other pages, and I'm asking **is there any method/pattern to implements other pages without creating different fragment classes, but only to use different viewModel type?**

Maybe some generic viewModel or something.

Comment: If the logic is common enough between the screens of the viewpager, then a generic viewmodel makes more sense. Then you can have child viewmodels that just pass in different dependencies to the constructor of the generic one and maybe overrides some functionality if necessary. From the fragment, you can create the viewmodel based on some parameter/category that the fragment takes when the fragment is created. Definitely possible. You need to provide more details on `lists in a recyclerview, of different data types`.

Answer (score 0):

**PageType**

```kotlin
enum class PageType {
    Page1, Page2, Page3;
}

val PageType.viewModelClass: KClass<out GenericViewModel>
    get() = when (this) {
        PageType.Page1 -> Page1ViewModel::class
        // todo
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```kotlin
abstract class GenericViewModel<T>() : BaseViewModel() {

    abstract val pageType: PageType
}

class Page1ViewModel @Inject constructor() : GenericViewModel() {
    override val pageType: PageType = PageType.Page1
}
```

**Fragment**

```kotlin
class PageFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private val pageType: PageType by lazy {
        TODO("read from arguments bundle")
    }

    private val vm: GenericViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(pageType.viewModelClass.java)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(type: PageType): PageFragment {
            TODO("add type into bundle and set as arguments")
        }
    }
}
```

If your current dagger setup works for viewmodels, then you won't have to do anything special to support this pattern.